# Using peered VPC security groups for Launch Configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have two VPCs, VPC-A & VPC-B which are peered in active state.

VPC-A has Security Group 'Bastion-SG' with inbound rules from my on-prem network. VPC-B has security group 'Support-SG' which has security group rules to other security groups in VPC-B.

The bastion is in an ASG in VPC-A, I want to give this EC2 machine both Bastion-SG and Support-SG so it has access from on-prem to VPC-B resources (via peering).

However, Launch Configuration does not allow this:

> All security groups should have the same VPC id (Service: AmazonAutoScaling; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError

What is the best way for me to link both security groups to my launch configuration?

**I could** add all the security group rules from Support-SG to Bastion-SG since the rules themselves can reference peered VPC groups.

**BUT** since the VPCs are part of different stacks, I would really prefer to keep the security groups separate.

Is there any way for me to link these security groups across VPCs?

Comment: Not sure what do you want to achieve? You want to associate a SG from VPC-B to instance in VPC-A?

Comment: Yeah that's right. I want to assign a SG from VPC-B to my launch configuration in VPC-A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to assign a SG from VPC-B to my launch configuration in VPC-A

Sadly, you can't do this. SG can only be used in VPC it was created in. From AWS docs:

> A security group can only be used in the VPC that you specify when you create the security group.

You can only reference it in an other VPC:

> If your VPC has a VPC peering connection with another VPC, a security group rule can reference another security group in the peer VPC

Comment: Thank you, I did think this was the only way but I was hoping there would be a way I could link them. Thanks for your answer.